# How to install a package not supported by condas

Tags: python, conda

I am trying out Anaconda on OS X and need to install the python package "npTDMS".

I tried

```
conda install nptdms
```

which gave me an error

> Error: No packages found in current osx-64 channels matching: nptdms
>   You can search for this package on Binstar with
>
> binstar search -t conda nptdms

So I tried that which found a package auto/nptdms for linux-64, which I assume won't work.

So, after some digging, I found [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640305/how-to-keep-track-of-pip-installed-packages-in-an-anaconda-conda-env)

and tried

```
conda skeleton pypi npTDMS
conda build npTMDS
```

which seemed to work (the tests passed.)

But then

```
import nptmds
```

returns

> ImportError: No module named nptdms

So I tried

```
conda pipbuild nptdms
```

which finished after a while with the error

> Error: package/name must be lowercase, got: u'npTDMS'

Can someone point me to a better set of instruction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
pip install npTDMS
```

There's nothing magical about Python run by Conda.  It can have access to Python packages anywhere, so long as they're in your path. Installing a package through the simplest way (generally pip or easy_install) should work fine.

(Also, "`import nptmds`" is not correct; try "`from nptdms import TdmsFile`")

Comment: So why use conda at all? Why not install everything using pip?

Comment: Conda is more than just an install manager, but if an install manager is all you want then you can install everything using pip.

Comment: Then I am confused about the difference between a package manager (conda) and an application that installs packages (pip) (Wikipedia calls both  pip and condo "package managers"). The only difference mentioned is that conda "Conda installs the Python programming language, while similar cross-platform package managers wheel or pip do not." Is that  all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda

Comment: But I suppose the question is still open why the combination 

"conda skeleton pypi npTDMS;
conda build npTMDS" did not work.

Comment: Did you try "from nptdms import TdmsFile" with that build?  Did "import nptmds" work with any other versions of python? Without trying it myself, I'd guess that either your import statement wasn't right, or that the path of the built package didn't match with the condo python.

Comment: Yes. I tried "from nptdms import TdmsFile" with that build and got "ImportError: No module named nptdms". How do I check the path is right?

Comment: `conda build` will only create the package. You can then distribute it (e.g. anaconda.org) and install with `conda install` into a conda environment.

Comment: I thought you weren't supposed to use pip with conda?

Comment: Using pip for something that there's a condo package for does get confusing, but if condo doesn't have the package using pip for it works fine

Answer (score 1):

**pip** is a package manager for Python. *As I understand*: **conda** can be used as a package manager for Python and other languages, as an inspection manager, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Conda environments (default 'root' on install) encapsulate and manage recipes that can leverage other package managers like pip (anaconda/bin/pip).  If the conda environment you want to install a PYTHON package into is already active in your path, then you can directly use pip.  If not, you should use the full path to pip within the conda environment directory you want to install to.

Also, you can always check conda channels to look for builds/recipes of packages that aren't available by default in pip or conda.  This includes non-python packages.  Many of these channels are discipline-specific.

For example, I routinely use the bioconda channel which includes bioinformatics recipes.  This is how I actively manage software like the bowtie2 aligner.

```
$ conda config --add channels bioconda
$ conda install bowtie2
```