# Python: installed selenium package not detected

Tags: python, selenium, pip, anaconda

I am using the [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) python distribution and would like to use the [selenium](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/index.html) package. Unfortunately the distribution does not have selenium included in it so I installed it using the recommended:

```
pip install -U selenium
```

the distribution [FAQ](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq.html#install-packages) say this should work fine but when I try to use it I get python telling me it does not know anything about this package.

i.e.

```
>>> import selenium
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

I checked and the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` directory does have selenium within it. How do I point my python distribution to this so I can use the package?

Comment: The reason this is happening might be because your Anaconda is pointing to a different python path whereas you are installing the modules in a different python path. That can only be the reason as far as I see, because I just did the same process and it easily imports the selenium package.

Comment: conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/metaperl selenium

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Following the advice of a comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640305/how-to-keep-track-of-pip-installed-packages-in-an-anaconda-conda-env?rq=1) question I installed Selenium using the `pip` installed with the distribution.

```
~/anaconda/bin/pip install -U selenium
```

I did not know about this before but it seems to have worked.

Comment: For Windows users, this also works if you run 'pip install -U selenium' inside the 'C:\Users\yourname\Anaconda3' directory with command prompt / power shell.

Answer (score 2):

Following works for me:

```
conda install -c conda-forge selenium
```

Please check [the Selenium page in Anaconda website](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/selenium) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
conda install -c metaperl selenium=2.40.0
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: This tried to force me to downgrade python 3.7 to 2.7, so be careful!