# python pip install not installing modules ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, selenium

Adding modules has been very confusing on my laptop. Whenever I run the `pip` command, it will appear to be successful – for example:

```
> pip install selenium
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): selenium in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

However, when I try to use it in running python example.py, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scriptattempt.py", line 2, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

Where this happens with pretty much any modules I try to import. Not exactly sure why, I installed python 3 in the past, so I wasn't sure if maybe that's causing problems. I tried `python3 example.py`, but got the same error for packages in the line before.
I looked in at my site-packages file, at location: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
but it's empty. Is this my problem? Is `pip` not unpacking in the correct location?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: installed selenium package not detected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450388/python-installed-selenium-package-not-detected)

Comment: If it's empty, then perhaps somebody deleted it from there, but didn't updated pip DB. Try to install it into user's folder with `pip install --user`, if you can't re-install it from scratch.