# no package gets installed using pip in anaconda

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

I have noticed that any package I install using `pip` gets installed in the default Python directory and not anaconda and this is very troubling. I tried to edit the `PATH` variable in my system using :

```
export PATH=/home/karen/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

The only thing I achived with this was that when I type python it starts anaconda (before, that command in the terminal just started the default python). So when I uninstall anaconda I can access the libraries I installed using `pip` in default python. So how can I fix this problem?

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep track of pip installed packages in an Anaconda (conda) env?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640305/how-to-keep-track-of-pip-installed-packages-in-an-anaconda-conda-env)

Comment: what's returned by running `pip -V`?

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is correct `which pip` will return the system installed pip, not the one in `/home/karen/anaconda3/bin`. If this is the case, then you can fix your issue with `conda install pip`. Then `pip install <some package>` will dump `<some package>` in to `/home/karen/anaconda3/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/<some package>`