# Difference between pip freeze and conda list

Tags: pip, conda

I am using both "pip freeze" and "conda list" to list the packages installed in my environment, but what are their differences?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33694864/1005215

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640305/how-do-i-keep-track-of-pip-installed-packages-in-an-anaconda-conda-environment

Comment: I have packages in my conda env that some were installed with conda and others were installed with pip (due to how libraries are support only in pip and that I use conda). So do I need to generate two `requiremen_{pip or conda}.py`? Or how do I solve this issue and install everything correctly?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

If the goal only is to list all the installed packages, `pip list` or `conda list` are the way to go.

`pip freeze`, like `conda list --export`, is more for generating requirements files for your environment. For example, if you have created a package in your customized environment with certain dependencies, you can do `conda list --export > requirements.txt`. When you are ready to distribute your package to other users, they can easily duplicate your environment and the associated dependencies with `conda create --name <envname> --file requirements.txt`.

The differences between `conda` and `pip` need a longer discussion. There are plenty of explanations on StackOverflow. [This article](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/) by Jake VanderPlas is a great read as well.

You might also find [this table](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands.html#conda-vs-pip-vs-virtualenv-commands) useful. It lists operation equivalences between `conda`, `pip` and `virtualenv`.

Comment: The beautiful table appears to have moved... 404!

Comment: Thanks a lot for noticing this! I wonder if this has something to do with the fact that fewer people could need `virtualenv` these days (`pyenv` and `pipenv` might have become the more dominant forces). Just corrected the link and limited the comparison to be between `pip` and `conda` (`virtualenv` no longer listed).

Comment: This site is my docs - always like to fix em ;-)  -  I added virtualenv again (it's in the table if you scroll right), feel free to delete the reference to it if you feel it reads better. (:

Comment: I came here looking for `conda list --export`. Consider another question answered from someone starting out with conda after using pip first.

Comment: While my code is running without any error, when I follow the 

"conda list --export > requirements.txt" and 
"conda create --name <envname> --file requirements.txt"

I got "Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages." , and cannot create environment. Any idea ?

Comment: @UğurGürkanTosun I don't see explicit issues in syntax. It is possible that you may not have started with a clean-slate environment when first running the codes (so the requirement file may have included pieces you don't need for your codes). Also, there is a difference between static and dynamic environment file. If you manage your environment entirely with conda, please also consider using yaml instead and only dictates versions when you truly need to. A good example can be seen in pyjantor repo: https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor/blob/dev/environment-dev.yml

Comment: I have packages in my conda env that some were installed with conda and others were installed with pip (due to how libraries are support only in pip and that I use conda). So do I need to generate two `requiremen_{pip or conda}.py`? Or how do I solve this issue and install everything correctly?

Comment: @CharlieParker Since we can always use pip within a conda environment, you don't need to have two separate files.  For example, when you run `conda list`, you should see `Build` and `Channel` columns clearly indicate if a package is installed via conda or pip:

```python
# Name.   Version.   Build.   Channel
pygments                  2.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 2.4.7                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.9.2           h2502468_0_cpython    conda-forge
```