# Set up virtualenv using a requirements.txt generated by conda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I'm setting up a python project, using an Anaconda virtual environment. I'm generating a requirements.txt so other people can easily set up their own virtual environment for the project.

I was wondering though, when other developers want to contribute to the project, but want to use virtualenv instead of Anaconda, can they do that?

I tried the following:

- I set up an empty project in an Anaconda environment and installed the aiohttp module. Then `conda list --export > requirements.txt` generates the following:

  ```
  # This file may be used to create an environment using:
  # $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
  # platform: win-64
  aiohttp=2.3.9=py36_0
  async-timeout=2.0.0=py36hc3e01a3_0
  certifi=2018.1.18=py36_0
  chardet=3.0.4=py36h420ce6e_1
  multidict=3.3.2=py36h72bac45_0
  pip=9.0.1=py36h226ae91_4
  python=3.6.4=h6538335_1
  setuptools=38.4.0=py36_0
  vc=14=h0510ff6_3
  vs2015_runtime=14.0.25123=3
  wheel=0.30.0=py36h6c3ec14_1
  wincertstore=0.2=py36h7fe50ca_0
  yarl=0.14.2=py36h27d1bf2_0
  ```
- I set up an empty project in a virtualenv environment and installed the aiohttp module there too. `pip freeze > requirements.txt` then generates:

  ```
  aiohttp==3.0.1
  async-timeout==2.0.0
  attrs==17.4.0
  chardet==3.0.4
  idna==2.6
  idna-ssl==1.0.0
  multidict==4.1.0
  yarl==1.1.0
  ```

So apparently both outputs are different, and my theory is: once I generate my requirements.txt with conda on my project, other developers can't choose virtualenv instead - at least not if they're not prepared to install a long list requirements by hand (it will be more than just the aiohttp module of course).

A first sight, importing the conda-generated requirements.txt in a project on virtualenv (`pip install -r requirements-conda.txt`) throws this error:

```
Invalid requirement: 'aiohttp=2.3.9=py36_0'
= is not a valid operator. Did you mean == ?
```

Am I right when I think that if developers would like to do this, they would need to programmatically change the package list to the format that virtualenv understands, or they would have to import all packages manually? Meaning that I impose them to choose conda as virtual environment as well if they want to save themselves some extra work?

Comment: The problem is not between `conda` and `virtualenv`, it is between `conda` and `pip`. And yes, the format between a conda environment.yml file and pip requirements.txt file are different. I'm not aware of any automatic converters between them.

Comment: Oh, OK, conda/pip as root issue makes sense.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

> I'm setting up a python project, using an Anaconda virtual environment. I was wondering though, when other developers want to contribute to the project, but want to use virtualenv instead of Anaconda, can they do that?

Yes - in fact this is how many of my projects are structured. To accomplish what you're looking for, here is a simple directory that we'll use as reference:

```
.
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
├── migrations
├── app.py
├── environment.yml
├── requirements.txt
```

In the project directory above, we have both **environment.yml** (for Conda users) and **requirements.txt** (for `pip`).

### `environment.yml`

> So apparently both outputs are different, and my theory is: once I generate my requirements.txt with conda on my project, other developers can't choose virtualenv instead - at least not if they're not prepared to install a long list requirements by hand (it will be more than just the aiohttp module of course).

To overcome this, we are using **two different environment files**, each in their own distinct format allowing for other contributors to pick the one they prefer. If Adam uses Conda to manage his environments, then all he need to do create his Conda from the `environment.yml` file:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

The first line of the yml file sets the new environment's name. This is how we create the Conda-flavored environment file. Activate your environment (`source activate` or `conda activate`) then:

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

In fact, because the environment file created by the `conda env export` command handles both the environment's `pip` packages and `conda` packages, we don't even need to have two distinct processes to create this file. `conda env export` will export all packages within your environment regardless of the channel they're installed from. It will have a record of this in `environment.yml` as well:

```
name: awesomeflask
channels:
- anaconda
- conda-forge
- defaults
dependencies:
- appnope=0.1.0=py36hf537a9a_0
- backcall=0.1.0=py36_0
- cffi=1.11.5=py36h6174b99_1
- decorator=4.3.0=py36_0
- ...
```

### `requirements.txt`

> Am I right when I think that if developers would like to do this, they would need to programmatically change the package list to the format that virtualenv understands, or they would have to import all packages manually? Meaning that I impose them to choose conda as virtual environment as well if they want to save themselves some extra work?

The recommended (and conventional) way to _change to the format that *pip understands* is through `requirements.txt`. Activate your environment (`source activate` or `conda activate`) then:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Say Eve, one of the project contributor want to create an identical virtual environment from `requirements.txt`, she can either:

```
# using pip
pip install -r requirements.txt

# using Conda
conda create --name <env_name> --file requirements.txt
```

A full discussion is beyond the scope of this answer, but [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249401/difference-between-pip-freeze-and-conda-list) are worth a read.

An example of `requirements.txt`:

```
alembic==0.9.9
altair==2.2.2
appnope==0.1.0
arrow==0.12.1
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astroid==2.0.2
backcall==0.1.0
...
```

### Tips: always create `requirements.txt`

In general, even on a project where all members are Conda users, I still recommend creating both the `environment.yml` (for the contributors) **as well as the `requirements.txt` environment file**. I also recommend having both these environment files tracked by version control early on (ideally from the beginning). This has many benefits, among them being the fact that it simplifies your debugging process and your deployment process later on.

A specific example that spring to mind is that of Azure App Service. Say you have a Django / Flask app, and want to deploy the app to a Linux server using Azure App Service with git deployment enabled:

```
az group create --name myResourceGroup --location "Southeast Asia"
az webapp create --resource-group myResourceGroup --plan myServicePlan
```

The service will look for two files, one being `application.py` and another being `requirements.txt`. You absolutely need both of these file (even if they're blank files) for the automation to work. This varies by cloud infrastructure / providers of course, but I find that having `requirements.txt` in our project generally saves us a lot of trouble down the road and worth the initial set-up overhead.

If your code is on GitHub, having `requirements.txt` also give you extra peace of mind by having its vulnerability detection pick up on any issue before alerting you / repo owner. That's a lot of great value for free, on the merit of having this extra dependency file (small price to pay).

[image: GitHub alerts]

This is as easy as making sure that every time a new dependency is installed, we run both the `conda env export` and `pip freeze > requirements.txt` command.

Comment: shouldn't the command for `# using Conda` be `conda env create --name <env_name> --file requirements.txt`?

Comment: @SanderVandenHautte, I'm hitting the same issue. Trying to create a virtualenv from the conda env. I got the `requirements.txt` but there are stuff in that file that are related to `conda` only. I removed some of them manually, still the installation fails. There should a way. Please put it here if you have any workaround for this.

Comment: To be honest @VenkateshDharavath there is nothing stopping two or more users who exclusively use pip to mess up the dependencies file the same way. User A uses venv. User B uses venv. User B added a bunch of lines that are not really dependencies to the project. User A remove them manually. So this isn't something that would be solved by removing conda from the workflow. It's also why code reviews and pull requests are essential

Comment: Yeah, I agree @onlyphantom

Comment: Very interesting thanks, but what if a developer on the team using pip adds new libraries to the the project with pip install, then updates the requirements.txt file only. Wouldn't the conda devs start having problems?

Answer (score 6):

### **I found these all commands very hardly and will put these below. Hope these commands will help you, If you have any questions just reply (Windows users)**

---

**For conda environment users follow these** (But first you need to install conda in your pc)

---

Create conda virtual environment:

> `conda create --name <env_name>`

See all modules installed in the environment as a list:

> `conda env list`

Import packages to your environment and create conda environment
(change environment name by editing the first line of
environment.yml file) (you can use whatever name for your environment.yml but usually it is named as environment.yml)

> `conda env create -f environment.yml`

Import packages to your environment and create conda environment
using pip environment

> `conda create --name <env_name> --file requirements.txt`

See imported packages:

> `conda list`

Activate the environment to export:

> `conda activate <env_name>` or `activate <env_name>`

Deactivate your conda environment:

> `conda deactivate`

Export your active environment to a new file:

> `conda env export > environment.yml`

---

### **This is for pip environment users**

Create virtual environment:

> `python -m venv (<env_name> or path)`

Can use python inside virtual environment by: (but this is annoying
and therefore normally we activate the environment and then use its
python using following **Activate virtual environment(for cmd) code**)

> `path\to\venv\Scripts\python.exe <file_name_path>`

Activate virtual environment (for cmd)

> `path\to\venv\Scripts\activate.bat`

Activate virtual environment (for powershell)

> `path\to\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1`

Deactivate your pip environment:

> `deactivate.bat`

Import packages in new virtual env

> `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Export your active environment to a new text file

> `pip freeze > requirements.txt`