# '=' is not a valid operator when trying to install packages with pip

Tags: python, pip, package

I am trying to install some packages from a .txt file. When I try to install them, `pip` is reading the file but is saying that `'=' is an invalid operator`. I have also tried changing the `'='` to `'=='` with no success.

For example, I am trying to install `aniso8601=8.0.0=py_0`, but keep getting the error:

```
ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'aniso8601=8.0.0=py_0' (from line 4 of requirements.txt)
Hint: = is not a valid operator. Did you mean == ?
```

> Edit: I was getting the list of dependencies from someone else and the py_0 portion was an oversight by me as it was something added that they left on the end of their list.

Comment: `pip install ansio8601==8.0.0`. Not sure what you expect from `=py_0`.

Comment: You're using a requirements.txt file generated with Anaconda, which is not the same as a requirements.txt file generated using pip: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787250/set-up-virtualenv-using-a-requirements-txt-generated-by-conda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you put `=py_0` and what it means, but here's an example of correct requirements file:

```
Jinja2==2.10.1
qtawesome==0.7.2
numpy==1.18.3
matplotlib==3.2.2
```

To install all dependencies use `pip install -r filename.txt`

To create a requirements file use `pip freeze > filename.txt`

Comment: It is an _anaconda_ requirements.txt that's why