# Procedure to determine how a requirements file was generated

Tags: pip, conda, requirements, invalid-characters

**Context**: I am working with python codes developed by different teams and each teams provides their corresponding requirements file. Trying to install the requirements via pip (`pip install -r requirements.txt`) is resulting in error of the following type:

```
ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'python-scipy = 0.18.1-2~pn1' (from line 13 of dependencies.txt)
Hint: = is not a valid operator. Did you mean == ?
```

and according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63995262/is-not-a-valid-operator-when-trying-to-install-packages-with-pip) a possible reason is that the requirements file I have are conda generated. When trying to install the requirements using conda (`conda install --file requirements.txt`) the following error appears:

```
InvalidVersionSpec: Invalid version '0.18.1-2~pn1': invalid character(s)
```

I don't know what is the standard procedure to determine how a requirements file was generated in order to determine how it should be installed.

**Questions**:

1. Given a requirements file, what is the standard procedure to use in order to determine how it was generated?
2. Do the the characters like "~" - appearing at the end of requirements - offer any hint about how the file was generated?
3. What else can I try to use in order to install the requirement file with requirements that contain such invalid characters for conda?

Comment: `I am working with python codes developed by different teams` <- Ask the teams for clarification

Comment: Doesn't look like Conda. There is no package named `python-scipy` in Anaconda Cloud.