# Creating requirements.txt in pip compatible format in a conda virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, conda, requirements.txt

I have created a conda virtual environment on a Windows 10 PC to work on a project. To install the required packages and dependencies, I am using `conda install <package>` instead of `pip install <package>` as per the best practices mentioned in https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment

In order to distribute my software, I choose to create an environment.yml and a requirements.txt file targeting the conda and non-conda users respectively. I am able to export the current virtual environment into a yml file, so the conda users are taken care of. But, for the non-conda users to be able to replicate the same environment, I need to create and share the requirements.txt file. This file can be created using `conda list --export > requirements.txt` but this format is not compatible with pip and other users can't use `pip install -r requirements.txt` on their systems.

Using `pip freeze > requiremens.txt` is a solution that is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787250/set-up-virtualenv-using-a-requirements-txt-generated-by-conda) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50777849/from-conda-create-requirements-txt-for-pip3). This means that non-conda users can simply execute `pip install -r requirements.txt` inside a virtual environment which they may create using virtualenv in the absence of conda.

However, if you generate a requiremets.txt file in the above style, you will end up with a requirements.txt file that has symbolic links. This is because we tried to create a requirements.txt file for packages that are installed using `conda install` and not `pip install`.
For example, the requirements.txt file that I generated in a similar fashion looks like this.

```
certifi==2020.6.20
cycler==0.10.0
kiwisolver==1.2.0
matplotlib @ file:///C:/ci/matplotlib-base_1603355780617/work
mkl-fft==1.2.0
mkl-random==1.1.1
mkl-service==2.3.0
numpy @ file:///C:/ci/numpy_and_numpy_base_1596215850360/work
olefile==0.46
pandas @ file:///C:/ci/pandas_1602083338010/work
Pillow @ file:///C:/ci/pillow_1602770972588/work
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
sip==4.19.13
six==1.15.0
tornado==6.0.4
wincertstore==0.2
```

These symbolic links will lead to errors when this file is used to install the dependencies.

Steps I took that landed me to the above requirements.txt file:

1. Created a new conda virtual environment using `conda create -n myenv python=3.8`
2. Activated the newly created conda virtual environment using `conda activate myenv`
3. Installed pip using `conda install pip`
4. Installed pandas using `conda intall pandas`
5. Installed matplotlib using `conda install matplotlib`
6. generated a pip compatible requrements.txt file using `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

So, my question is how do you stick to the best practice of using `conda install` instead of `pip install` while still being able to distribute your software package to both conda and non-conda users?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The best solution I've found for the above is the combination I will describe below. For `conda`, I would first export the environment list as `environment.yml` and omit the package build numbers, which is often what makes it hard to reproduce the environment on another OS:

```
conda env export > environment.yml --no-builds
```

Output:

```sh
name: myenv
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - blas=1.0
  - ca-certificates=2020.10.14
  - certifi=2020.6.20
...
```

For `pip`, what you describe above is apparently a [well-known issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8176) in more recent versions of pip. The workaround to get a "clean" `requirements.txt` file, is to export as such:

```
pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt
```

Output:

```sh
certifi==2020.6.20
cycler==0.10.0
kiwisolver==1.2.0
matplotlib==3.3.2
mkl-fft==1.2.0
...
```

Notice that the above are different between `pip` and `conda` and that is most likely because `conda` is more generic than `pip` and includes not only Python packages.

Personally, I have found that for distributing a package, it is perhaps more concise to determine the minimum set of packages required and their versions by inspecting your code (what imports do you make?), instead of blindly exporting the full `pip` or `conda` lists, which might end up (accidentally or not) including packages that are not really necessary to use the package.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! @tania. The requirements.txt created with the --format=freeze flag is indeed the clean version, i.e., without the symbolic links. The answer is also helpful in understanding the differences between the two and the key things to consider in such scenarios.

Comment: @tania I wrote a package that does just what you described at the end.  https://anaconda.org/jamespreed/conda-minify it uses a directed acyclic graph to find the top-level packages that all other packages can be derived from as dependencies.

Comment: @James That's amazing! :D Will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 1):

On you bash shell you can simply run
`conda list | awk {'print $1'} |sed '/#/d;/_/d'> requirements.txt`

In above code, I am just getting the dependencies name and removing lines starting with `#` and `_` from the file.This will not include any version of the dependencies.
*This could be run as bash script.

Answer (score 1):

`pip freeze` returns *all* packages that are installed in the environment.

Use `pipreqs` to include *only* the packages that are used by your application based on imports.

##### Example

```bash
pip install pipreqs
```

After installing, do

```bash
pipreqs /home/project/location
Successfully saved requirements file in /home/project/location/requirements.txt
```

The resulting `requirements.txt`:

```
wheel==0.23.0
Yarg==0.1.9
docopt==0.6.2
```

Check the [docs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs#example) for more.