# How to start a flask app from terminal with conda environment

Tags: python, flask, conda

My Flask app environment is using anaconda

When I use IDE like PyCharm, it provides a terminal which already in the specific conda environment, like this:

[image: terminal session showing flask run]

It could easily let me to start the app via command `flask run`

**Then my question is, how could I start the app in an original terminal?**

I tried to use `flask run` in the original terminal but the dependency module are not found (All dependencies are placed in the conda environment actually)

Comment: Have you created a virtual environment and installed all the necessary packages?

Comment: Maybe you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787250/set-up-virtualenv-using-a-requirements-txt-generated-by-conda/55687210#55687210) to setup your project.

Comment: At the top of your image, there's a line that starts with `(flask_env_3)`. That's the name of the virtual environment your flask app needs to be in to run. You can activate it by running `source flask_env_3/bin/activate` in the terminal (in the root folder of your app), and then `flask run` should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `conda run` for this. E.g.,

```bash
conda run -n flask_env_3 flask run
```

You may need to add the flag(s) `--live-stream` or `--no-capture-output` (or both), for interactivity.

Comment: BTW, if you do need either of those flags, please let us know, or edit it into the answer.