# How to move from pip to anaconda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I'm a beginner trying to play around with machine learning. I downloaded python, and used `pip` to download libraries like TensorFlow, Pandas, Numpy, etc.

Now, I find that Anaconda is a better package manager to use for machine learning. I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do. Do I have to download all the libraries with Anaconda (which I tried to do with Pandas, and it said the library is already downloaded)?

Could you guys explain to me how I can move from using pip to using anaconda? I really don't understand environments, and this package manager stuff, so please help me!

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed)

Answer (score 0):

In principle there is no need to change your package manager. Simply switch to do `conda install` the next time you would do `pip install`. Think of it like this: Do you have to re-download **everything** when switching from internet-explorer to firefox? Probably, some things work a little different between `conda` and `pip` but for a basic beginner, these differences should be neglectable.

You could freeze your pip packages and re-install them inside a conda environment to have everything (e.g. package dependencies) neatly managed by Anaconda, which is imho good practice. Pip packages will be available in every subsequent created conda environment, so if you want to use different packages in different environments, better re-install those using conda.

There is some non-trivial difference between conda and pip, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249401/difference-between-pip-freeze-and-conda-list) and [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/).

Comment: *Do you have to re-download everything when switching from internet-explorer to firefox?* Yes, you have to download new themes, plugins and extensions; and you have to configure them in a different ways…

Comment: Emphasis on everything

Comment: Good answer. Using critical thinking and context clues (concepts taught in grade school), I understood your answer and your analogy completely. Thank you. Sorry someone down-voted you.

Answer (score 0):

Best practices are to use different environment for different purposes. On a conda environment, download or re-download all requirement packages for that environment. Also always install a conda package only after you are done with pip install. Using both two environment, be sure not use the "--user" on pip as conda have user priviledge issues connecting to packages installed by pip.
You can check this [link](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment) for more information