# Installed packages using pip don't seen by conda list

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, conda

I opened the command prompt on Ubuntu. Then, I created a new environment with `conda create -n newEnv python=3.6.9` command.Then I activated the `newEnv` enviroment with using `conda activate newEnv` command. After that, I saw the pre-installed packages which comes with `python=3.6.9` with using `conda list` command. The output was like this:

```
# packages in environment at /home/t/anaconda3/envs/newEnv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
ca-certificates           2019.5.15                  ....   
certifi                   2019.6.16                  ....
libedit                   3.1.20181209               ....
libffi                    3.2.1                      ....
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                      ....
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                      ....
ncurses                   6.1                        ....
openssl                   1.1.1c                     ....
pip                       19.2.2                     ....
python                    3.6.9                      ....
readline                  7.0                        ....
setuptools                41.0.1                     ....  
sqlite                    3.29.0                     ....
tk                        8.6.8                      ....
wheel                     0.33.4                     ....   
xz                        5.2.4                      ....
zlib                      1.2.11                     ....
```

For me, everything is normal until now. After that, I installed the `pandas` package with using `pip install pandas` command, It gives an output like this:

```
Installing collected packages: numpy, pytz, six, python-dateutil, pandas
Successfully installed numpy-1.17.1 pandas-0.25.1 python-dateutil-2.8.0 pytz-2019.2 six-1.12.0
```

However, after that, when I type `conda list` command, I couldn't see the successfully installed packages like pandas, numpy,pytz etc(installed with pandas above). conda list gave same output like this:

```
# packages in environment at /home/t/anaconda3/envs/newEnv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
ca-certificates           2019.5.15                  ....   
certifi                   2019.6.16                  ....
libedit                   3.1.20181209               ....
libffi                    3.2.1                      ....
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                      ....
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                      ....
ncurses                   6.1                        ....
openssl                   1.1.1c                     ....
pip                       19.2.2                     ....
python                    3.6.9                      ....
readline                  7.0                        ....
setuptools                41.0.1                     ....  
sqlite                    3.29.0                     ....
tk                        8.6.8                      ....
wheel                     0.33.4                     ....   
xz                        5.2.4                      ....
zlib                      1.2.11                     ....
```

Why don't seen the `pandas` package in the output of the `conda list` command? Although it is succesfully installed with `pip install pandas` command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between pip freeze and conda list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249401/difference-between-pip-freeze-and-conda-list)

Comment: Can you verify that those packages actually installed in the env (i.e., `/home/t/anaconda3/envs/newEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages`)?  Generally, it is bad practice to use `pip` to install packages that are readily available through Anaconda Cloud. Please read "[*Using Pip in a Conda Environment*](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)".

Answer (score 2):

Conda will list packages installed by conda.

You would better off using Conda to install pandas.

```
conda activate newEnv
conda install pandas
```

Although conda and pip can see each other's packages (mostly), you are better off sticking to one or the other to avoid conflicts.

Comment: But I want to use pip, why conda can't see the installed packages by pip.

Comment: @EasterGamer why do you want to use `pip` to install a package that is available via `conda`?

Comment: @EasterGamer you're really better off not using `pip` when possible. See "[Using Pip in a Conda Environment](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)."  It can lead to an unstable environment, and `pip` and `conda` don't have full interoperability. It's mainly provided as a convenience, for packages that aren't available through Conda channels.