# using requirements.txt to automatically install packages from conda channels and pip in a new conda environment

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to set a conda environment using a `requirements.txt` file that a coworker shared with me. My coworker uses Python in a Mac without Anaconda, and I'm using it in a Windows machine with Anaconda. The file `requirements.txt` was generated with the command `pip freeze` and looks like this:

```
absl-py==0.7.1
affine==2.3.0
agate==1.6.0
agate-dbf==0.2.0
agate-excel==0.2.1
agate-sql==0.5.2
...
```

After checking the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787250/set-up-virtualenv-using-a-requirements-txt-generated-by-conda), I tried the following in the Anaconda terminal:

```
conda create --name my-env-name --file requirements.txt
```

Which fails with the following error message:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - appscript==1.0.1
  - style==1.1.0
  - senticnet==1.3
  - scikits.optimization==0.3
...
```

My understanding is that this happens because those packages are not available in the Anaconda package installation channels, and that they should be installed instead via `pip` with my conda environment activated, using `pip install -r requirements.txt`

The problem is that this list of packages is very long, and I would like to avoid having to manually check and separating which packages are included in Anaconda channels and which should be installed via `pip`. Then, is there a way to tell Anaconda to create an environment by automatically recognizing the packages included in its channels, installing them, and then installing the rest using `pip`?

Comment: `requirements.txt` is a different format from the output that conda expects. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249401/difference-between-pip-freeze-and-conda-list

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Using `requirements.txt` with conda

There's no problem at all using a `requirements.txt` file when creating a conda environment.

In fact, you can also set additional channels at creation time:

```
conda create --name my-env-name --file requirements.txt --channel <NAME_OF_CHANNEL>
```

for example, in the case of the first package you mention, you can install it from `anaconda` channel. So you could run:

```
conda create --name my-env-name --file requirements.txt --channel default --channel anaconda
```

Why using `default` channel first? Well, just to give preference to the default one (the priority of channels is specified by the order they are listed: higher priority from left to right).

### When at least some of the packages are not available using conda

Well, when no conda channel can provide any of your required packages, there are several alternatives:

1. Install through conda those packages available in any of its channels.
2. Install through pip the rest.
3. Create a conda `environment.yml` file:

   ```
    conda env export > environment.yml
   ```

When you need to recreate this environment, then you can do:

```
conda env create --name my-env-name --file environment.yml
```

and it will install the packages using conda, will install pip, and then will install those packages only available with the latter one.

This approach has good and bad properties:

- one of the good properties is that it separates those packages installed through conda from those installed using pip.
- one of the bad properties is that it's only useful for conda, but not for pip alone.