# Anaconda and geograpy

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, linux-mint, geograpy

First of all, I'm a really newbie to python and anaconda, so please take this under consideration when replying my question :).

I have a Jupyter notebook and I would like to use [geograpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geograpy) library there. But I have no idea how to install it into anaconda.

On this library website there is manual how to install it using pip - but i believe this is something else.

Any hints would be more than welcome :)

EDIT

After trying `pip install geograpy` I have following error

```
Rolling back uninstall of Pillow
Command "/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-tcpdwncf/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-az_qg2uz-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-tcpdwncf/Pillow/
```

Comment: does `conda install geography` work?

Comment: No, it doesn't :(

Comment: oh. what's wrong with pip then?

Comment: Hmm using pip install will allow me to install this also in anaconda env?

Comment: I don't see that lib in anaconda-navigator. Have you tried just `pip install geography`?

Comment: According to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640305/how-do-i-keep-track-of-pip-installed-packages-in-an-anaconda-conda-environment) if pip was installed by anaconda conda will keep track of any packages you install through pip

Comment: Please see my edit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Pillow was causing a problem. But follow and installing additionaly tool for it solved a problem.

However, when anybody else will try to use gergrapy, then wach out- it works only for Python 2 :(

Answer (score 0):

There should be an Anaconda Prompt (use the Windows search bar) that you can navigate to (looks like a command window once you open it), and

```
pip install geography
```

should work there.  There may be a more technical answer to this, but this is the approach that always works for me when pip install does not in the command window.

Comment: The libraries I install through the Anaconda Prompt remain separate from the usual pip install in the command window for some reason.  If you are having the same issue, this may help out

Comment: Thanks for hint, but I'm using linux mint