# custodian object not found exception

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, cloudcustodian

I am using Anaconda as python package manager, but I couldn't find the c7n module available in conda env to install.

So I installed c7n module using pip in anaconda prompt, but when I use `conda list` it is not showing c7n as installed.

I hope this issue already been resolved, can anyone let me know the missing piece here ?

### Edit 1:

commands used in anaconda prompt

```
conda activate myenv
pip install c7n
```

After executing pip install I can see c7n is getting downloaded, but when i execute `custodian schema` in conda prompt itself, it is throwing below error.

Error:

```
'custodian' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

By executing `where python` am getting below response.

Response:

```
c:\Users\rthiyagaraja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\python.exe
C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
```

when I tried downloading c7n again using pip command I got below response

```
Requirement already satisfied: C7n in c:\users\rthiyagaraja\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (0.9.33)
Requirement already satisfied: boto3==1.33.1 in c:\users\rthiyagaraja\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from C7n) (1.33.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3==1.26.18 in c:\users\rthiyagaraja\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from C7n) (1.26.18)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema==4.20.0 in c:\users\rthiyagaraja\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from C7n) (4.20.0)
Requirement already satisfied: argcomplete==3.1.6 in c:\users\rthiyagaraja\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from C7n) (3.1.6)
```

so I have created new env out of this path by using below command in conda prompt

```
conda create --prefix c:\users\rthiyagaraja\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages --copy python=3.8
```

and activated using below command

```
conda activate c:\users\rthiyagaraja\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages
```

but when I list the installed packages it is not showing the c7n module, but when I try to install using pip it is showing C7n satisfied error which I mentioned above.

### Edit 2: Answer (This is for those who are looking for answers)

Trying to install custodian in default env or conda env didn't worked.

So I installed in Virtual env, follow below steps.

```
python -m venv custodian 

.\custodian\scripts\activate 

pip install c7n

.\custodian\scripts\activate
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I keep track of pip-installed packages in an Anaconda (Conda) environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640305/how-do-i-keep-track-of-pip-installed-packages-in-an-anaconda-conda-environment)

Comment: Please show commands used. For example, rather than *"I installed c7n module"*, state something like *"I used `conda activate myenv; pip install -U c7n`"* or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Have updated the thread with the commands used and the error message as well, still am struck with this. let me know the proper way to install it.